# Regex for word and 2 numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex on an input string for a name and 2 numbers separated by a comma and another word(words in capital):

```
PETER 1,2 PARENT //valid
PETER 1,2 //invalid
PETER 1,PARENT //invalid
```

What would the regex for this be?  The numbers range from 0-4.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Try going here and testing some regular expressions of your own. It should be a good exercise: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I tried ^\A-Zd[0-4],d[0-4]\A-Z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[A-Z]+ [0-4],[0-4] [A-Z]+$/

^         // start match
[A-Z]+    // one or more capital letters
          // one space
[0-4]     // a number between 0 and 4
,         // comma
[0-4]     // a number between 0 and 4
          // one space
[A-Z]+    // one or more capital letters
$         // end match
```

[image]

[image: regex]

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try?

`.+\s\d+,\d+\s.+`, that means;

1) .+ -> (any character except new line) match one or more

2) \s -> match space

3) \d+ -> (any digit) match one or more

4) , -> match comma

5) match 3, 2 and 1